# @Html.TextBoxFor textbox isn't highlighted after failing validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 with Razor. For input I have two types of control:

1. `@Html.TextBoxFor`
2. `@Html.TextAreaFor`

Both have required field validation. `@Html.TextAreaFor` highlight the box if validation fails where as `@Html.TextBoxFor` does not.

Here is my code

HTML:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Why is the textbox created using `@Html.TextBoxFor` not hightlighted when its validation fails?

Comment: Is is not validating or not *highlighting*? If it's not highlighting, it's probably a CSS problem.

Comment: It is validating but not highlighting. CSS? where I should look? 
I am not sure, only other two - DropDownListFor and TextAreaFor are showing the red boxes after the validation fails but not the "TextBoxFor" which I wanted.

Comment: The default CSS will be in `/Content/site.css` unless it's been moved. When the text box is in an invalid state, look at the page source--what class(es) are applied, etc? To view source, I would *highly* recommend familiarizing yourself with your browser's available tools e.g. Firefox = Firebug, Chrome or IE = press F12 for built-in tools, Opera = Dragonfly, etc

Comment: CSS is good.

class="input-validation-error" is there after postback in both

Answer (score 10):

Make sure the variables you're assigning to these input fields are [Required] in your model class.. Also did you strip out any css in a "clean up" process? Try adding this if it's not in there.

```
.field-validation-error
{
color: #ff0000;
}
.field-validation-valid
{
display: none;
}
.input-validation-error
{
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
background-color: #ffeeee;
}
.validation-summary-errors
{
font-weight: bold;
color: #ff0000;
}
.validation-summary-valid
{
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem myself. I added a new CSS class to the `Site.css` file (or whatever style sheet you prefer).

```
textarea.input-validation-error {
border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue today:

In order to raise validation for textbox or any other field you just need these two lines:

In controller: `ModelState.AddModelError("ErrorEmail", "Error Message");`

In View: `@Html.ValidationMessage("ErrorEmail")`

**And in web.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

It was overwriting validation css with my own website css so that's why it was not showing red border around textbox.

**making validation error style important resolved my problem:**

```
input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d !important;
}
```

Comment: My validation.css was being overridden by bootstrap. !important fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have client-side validation, you need to ensure that you have the necessary scripts included in your View (whether it is through the _Layout.cshtml view or your direct view).  Put this at the top of your view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Ensure the path and the script names are correct.  This will enable you to utilize client-side validation (i.e. highlighting the text box).

Comment: I have them in my _Layout.cshtml  at at top. I also tried them putting in my view. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add both .input-validation-error and .input.input-validation-error classes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anyone else is searching this, ensure you also use

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

After your textbox